# Sorting index entries with accented words

Tags: indexing, sorting

Friends, I'm struggling for some time with this disturbance in the TeX force:

I have a set of words in Portuguese which are accented. When sorting these words, we treat accented letters the same way as their accentless counterparts. So, a list with these words:

```
abacate
ábaco
alavanca
árvore
arte
ácaro
aba
```

is sorted as

```
aba
abacate
ábaco
ácaro
alavanca
arte
árvore
```

When using these words as index entries, the accented letters are sorted via `makeindex` as symbols:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\textit{"
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{imakeidx}[2012/05/09]

\def\pfill{\unskip~\dotfill\penalty500 
  \strut\nobreak\dotfil~\ignorespaces}

\def\efill{\hfill\nopagebreak}

\def\dotfil{\leaders\hbox to.6em{\hss.\hss}\hfil}

\makeindex[name=words,columns=1,options=-s mystyle]
\begin{document}

Hello world.

\index[words]{abacate}
\index[words]{ábaco}
\index[words]{alavanca}
\index[words]{árvore}
\index[words]{arte}
\index[words]{ácaro}
\index[words]{aba}

\printindex[words]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Marco Daniel brilliantly suggested me in the chat to try `xindy` instead of `makeindex`. So

```
xindy -M texindy -C utf8 -L portuguese filename.idx
```

produces the "correct" sorting (in Portuguese of course, I'm aware that other languages have different rules).

Unfortunately, I use some custom styles for my indices (we can see one of them above). For my despair, `xindy` works quite differently than `makeindex`, and that `.ist` style of mine is not supported AFAIK.

It would be fine for me to move to `xindy` if I could also port my `.ist` styles as well.

The workaround I'm using right now is to provide an accentless word before the "correct" one:

```
\index[words]{abacate}
\index[words]{abaco@ábaco}
\index[words]{alavanca}
\index[words]{arvore@árvore}
\index[words]{arte}
\index[words]{acaro@ácaro}
\index[words]{aba}
```

[image: Output 2]

This one works. `:)`

Is it possible to provide a sorting rule to `makeindex`, or maybe providing similar `.ist` styles to `xindy`? I'm fine with the current workaround, but it's quite painful to remove every single accent from my index entries. I'd prefer to stick with `makeindex`, if possible. `:)`

Comment: It is hopeless to stay with `makeindex`, what special things does your `.ist` do? Note that `texindy` adds a lot of things people have to add manually with `makeindex`

Comment: @daleif: I've never used `texindy` before, this is actually my first try. `:)` My `.ist`'s are not complex, they are very similar to the one from my question, I usually have some TikZ in the header parts. I'd be glad to try other approaches. `:)`

Comment: Did you have a look into the default output (the `.ind`) file that `texindy` provide? It make use of two macros to typeset the header parts, `\lettergroupDefault` (the non-alfabetical one) and `\lettergroup`, both are defined in the `.ind` file if not already defined by the user. The `\dotfill` part should not be that hard to add using a custom style.

Comment: If you are able to program in TeX, you may adapt my `esindex` to Portuguese (it's intended for Spanish). It uses makeindex and there are options for setting  how accented letters (or italics) are sorted, particles to be removed from the key sort, letter-by-letter vs. word-by-word, and more. But as I've said, it's intended for Spanish, so I presume vowels with tilde doesn't work as you could expect.

Comment: You could simply try `\index{abaco@ábaco}` as introduced in the [MakeIndex](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeindex) manual. But probably the proposed solutions with Xindy are more reliable for future projects.

Comment: @JavierBezos: I was unaware of your package, it's awesome! My Spanish is far from acceptable, but I was able to follow the manual. It's a clever implementation! Since my TeX-fu is still very basic (I'm still struggling with the TeXbook), it might take a while for me to come up with a similar idea. `:)`

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: I'm currently using this workaround, thankfully it works. `:)` `xindy` seems to be the next step and might save time for me in the future, since Portuguese has lots of accented words. `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the simple solution. Well, not so simple, after all. :)

One small problem, that I'll solve in a next release of `imakeidx`: for some reason (that I don't remember now) we decided that `program=xindy` called `texindy` anyway. But unfortunately, it seems that the calls

```
xindy -M mystyle -C utf8 -L portuguese words.idx
```

and

```
texindy -M mystyle -C utf8 -L portuguese words.idx
```

are *not* equivalent, as the latter throws up an incomprehensible error (probably a bug in the `texindy` script).

Thus the following document will require to run manually `xindy` (but you have Arara, so it's not a problem), until the small problems are corrected.

Notice that `xindy` provides two commands for the letter groups, which should be redefined in the preamble to do what's wanted.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.xdy}
(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill " :sep "\dotfill ")
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{imakeidx}[2012/05/09]
\newcommand*{\lettergroupDefault}[1]{}
\newcommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
  \par\textit{#1}\par
  \nopagebreak
  }

\def\pfill{\unskip~\dotfill\penalty500 
  \strut\nobreak\dotfil~\ignorespaces}

\def\efill{\hfill\nopagebreak}

\def\dotfil{\leaders\hbox to.6em{\hss.\hss}\hfil}

\makeindex[name=words,columns=1,program=xindy,options=-M texindy -M mystyle -C utf8 -L portuguese]
\begin{document}

Hello world.

\index[words]{abacate}
\index[words]{ábaco}
\index[words]{alavanca}
\index[words]{árvore}
\index[words]{arte}
\index[words]{ácaro}
\index[words]{aba}

\printindex[words]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Joachim mentioned that at some point. Rather anoying.

Comment: @daleif There's a `tex/inputenc/` hardcoded in `texindy` that should be removed, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I just wonder why there hasn't been any updates to `xindy`....

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation, egreg! `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use @ in the index entry and type the word without an accent to be indexed.

```
\index{Etica@Ética}
```

This will make the word appear in the index as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here a solution using only a style file.

The style consists only of two line:

```
(markup-locclass-list  :open " \dotfill\ "   ) 

(markup-letter-group  :open-head "\textit{" :close-head "}" )
```

Here a complete MWE which needs shell-escape.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.xdy}
;;; xindy style file

;;;dotted line between name and page number
(markup-locclass-list  :open " \dotfill\ "   ) 

(markup-letter-group  :open-head "\textit{" :close-head "}" ) 

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{imakeidx}[2012/05/09]

\def\pfill{\unskip~\dotfill\penalty500 
  \strut\nobreak\dotfil~\ignorespaces}

\def\efill{\hfill\nopagebreak}

\def\dotfil{\leaders\hbox to.6em{\hss.\hss}\hfil}

\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-M mystyle.xdy,name=words,columns=1]


\begin{document}

Hello world.

\index[words]{abacate}
\index[words]{ábaco}
\index[words]{alavanca}
\index[words]{árvore}
\index[words]{arte}
\index[words]{ácaro}
\index[words]{aba}

\printindex[words]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I need a little more space, but something like this:

```
\newcommand\lettergroup[1]{%
  \par\textit{#1}\par
  \nopagebreak}
\newcommand\lettergroupDefault[1]{\lettergroup{#1}}
```

and a new module (`mystyle.xdy`):

```
(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfil ")
```

Then invoke `texindy` via

```
texindy -M mystyle.xdy ....
```

that seems to do the same as your MWE, just with `texindy` instead

Comment: How nice! The "style" is written in Lisp! `:)` I'll take a look on the examples in the `xindy` folder. Thanks! (BTW sorry for the delay on upvoting and commenting your answer, I was out of votes)

Comment: the `xindy` internals is written in Lisp (AFAIR)