# How to configure Xindy in TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter, xindy

I'm using TeXnicCenter with TeX Live and want to switch from MakeIndex to Xindy. Is it enough to change the path of the compiler in the profile section to xindy.exe, or do I have change the parameters and/or post processing, too?

I know the [manual](http://www.xindy.org/doc/manual.html), but its overwhelming me to get the right parameter and perhaps post processing configuration.

Comment: Side note: [How to use Xindy with MiKTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex)

Comment: The standard parameter are `"%tm.idx" -t "%tm.ilg" -o "%tm.ind"`.

Comment: So, exactly like with MiKTeX. See my answer and comment there, if something’s unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, the command line parameters have to be adapted as well.

Which one to use depends on your needs. I use MiKTeX, but presuming in TeX Live the commands are the same, then the parameters for MakeIndex are `"%tm.idx" -t "%tm.ilg" -o "%tm.ind"`.

Both `-t` and `-o` can be preserved, but I guess you need to add a language option `-L` and/or one or more module options `-M` and perhaps `-C` for the codepage. Not to forget: `"%tm.idx"` must come in last position.

Also, if you’d rather use `texindy` then pure `xindy` the needed parameters may be slightly different.

Compare some answers here on TeX.SX: egreg’s answer to [Sorting index entries with accented words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58010/sorting-index-entries-with-accented-words/58016#58016) or the answers to [How to use xindy with XeTeX/LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25623/how-to-use-xindy-with-xetex-luatex).

---

On the other hand you could consider in using the package `imakeidx` or switching to `arara`.

Comment: I load the package `makeidx` and only use the parameters `-L german-duden "%tm.idx"` for texindy. If I need more, I will take a look at the modules that are described here: http://www.xindy.org/doc/texindy-man.pdf

Comment: Sorry, I took `imakeidx` which provides more than one index.